# Error in approxfun(x.values.1, y.values.1, method = "constant", f = 1, : zero non-NA points

Tags: r, package

I am using R's ROCR package to calculate the area under the curve of large data-sets. However, The code does not work for all the datasets except a few.

the code i have used:

```
   pred <- prediction(mydata$Total.Regexes, mydata$actual)
   perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
```

I checked the dataset there is no non-Na points present in the dataset. However, since the dataset is huge, it may go out of my sight. So, is there any other process to refine the dataset (for non-NA values, if there any) without disturbing the remaining values?

And this is the error it shows for a few dataset:

```
 Error in approxfun(x.values.1, y.values.1, method = "constant", f = 1,  : 
          zero non-NA points
```

I checked using:

```
is.na(dataset)
dataset <- na.omit(dataset)
```

but still it doesn't work. There is no non-Na values present in the dataset.. I can't reproduce the error with a simple dataset, so I've posted the problem dataset in my dropbox.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjko6o6h23m43le/DC4.csv

Please Help!

Comment: The `na.omit` should remove all rows with any `NA` values so that seems unlikely to be a problem. You need to be sure your each of your sets have negative and positive values otherwise you can't evaluate performance. But what you've posted is insufficient to reproduce the problem. You must edit and provide some sample data that will trigger the error otherwise we are unable to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

By "casting" the arguments to `prediction` I managed to get everything working properly.

Try:

```
pred <- prediction(as.numeric(mydata$Total.Regexes), as.numeric(mydata$actual))
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the same error since arguments to prediction were matrices in my case, not vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. This is a 'bad' way to solve it:

> MODEL <- glm(y ~ x + z, my_data, family = "binomial")
>   pred_probab <- predict(MODEL, type = "response")
>
> #### type = "response"is specified for return prediction sample as probabilities
>
> pr <- prediction(pred_probab, Two_levels_factor) 
>   Error in approxfun(x.values.1, y.values.1, method = "constant", f = 1,  : 
>     zero non-NA points

The sample "Two_levels_factor" with `n = 2000` has only one level value "positive_result". For logit regression it must have two levels.

> levels(Two_levels_factor)
>   [1] "negative_result"
>   Two_levels_factor[1] <- "positive_result"
>   levels(Two_levels_factor)
>   [1] "positive_result" "negative_result"
>
> pr <- prediction(pred_probab, Two_levels_factor)